# java CompletableFuture.thenCombine returns CompletableFuture of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, parallel-processing, nonblocking, chaining, completable-future

I have 3 different methods in my application. All are returning `CompletableFuture<SomeType>`. I want to execute method 1 and 2 in parallel. On completion of method 1 and 2, I want to trigger method 3 with parameters from method 1 and 2 return values.

Code example :

```
CompletableFuture<Request> future1 = RequestConverter.Convert(requestDto);
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = tokenProvider.getAuthToken();

CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>> future3 = 
future1.thenCombine(future2,(request,token) -> 
requestProcessor.Process(request,token));
```

But the problem with the above code is that I am getting a `CompletableFuture` of `CompletableFuture`. I want to avoid this and get a simple `CompletableFuture<String>` without blocking. Is this possible?

Comment: What about ```thenCompose```?

Comment: My understanding is "thenCompose" can be used only if we need result from only one CompletableFuture. But in this case i need result of both the CompletableFuture to trigger my third method.

Comment: I am getting a compile time exception if i use thenCompose. I am new to Java, so maybe i am missing some syntax. Can you please post the future3  syntax with your suggestion.

Comment: First use combine then compose, I will post my code soon.

Comment: I will try as per your suggestion. Please post your code as well, so that i can cross check whether my code is inline. Thanks

Comment: Note that java standards recommend that method and variable names start with a lowercase letter while class names start with an uppercase one. The syntax highlighting gets a bit messed up here since this convention is not followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have the `Pair` class.

```
class Pair<L, R> {
    public final L left;
    public final R right;

    public Pair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Then you can first combine to a pair then compose.

```
CompletableFuture<Request> future1 = RequestConverter.Convert(requestDto);
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = tokenProvider.getAuthToken();

CompletableFuture<String> future3 = future1
    .thenCombine(future2, Pair::new)
    .thenCompose(pair -> requestProcessor.Process(pair.left, pair.right));
```

Answer (score 6):

As there is no method that *combines* `thenCombine()` and `thenCompose()`, you can use `thenCompose()` to unwrap nested `CompletableFuture`s coming from your `thenCombine()`:

```
CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<String>> future3 = 
    future1.thenCombine(future2, (request,token) -> 
        requestProcessor.Process(request,token));

CompletableFuture<String> future4 = future3.thenCompose(c -> c);
```

Comment: This avoids the extra class. Thanks.